# In a finite cyclic group, the generator has the order of the group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group of order $n$ generated by an element $g$. I want to show that the order of $g$ is exactly the order of $G$.

My try:

We can write $G=\{g^i\;|\;i\in \mathbb Z\}$. Since $G$ is finite, we know that there will be identifications $g^i=g^j$ that will make $G$ finite. By the multiplication law on $G$ we must have $g^0=1$. Also if $i<j$ and if $g^i=g^j$ then $g^{j-i}=1$. I can see all these but not see why $g^n=1$ and not $g^k=1$ for all $0<k<n$? Thank your for your help!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $g\in G$ has order $k$ then set $\left\{ e,g,\ldots,g^{k-1}\right\} $ has distinct elements and $\left\{ g^{i}\mid i\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} =\left\{ e,g,\ldots,g^{k-1}\right\} $.
Here $e$ stands for the identity of $G$.

If secondly $G$ is generated by $g$ then $G=\left\{ g^{i}\mid i\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} =\left\{ e,g,\ldots,g^{k-1}\right\} $
and consequently $\left|G\right|=k$, *i.e.*, the order of $G$ is exactly
the order of $g$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Please just tell me in the first paragraph why the elements $e,g,...,g^{k-1}$ must be distinct.

Comment: The order of $g$ is by definition the *smallest* positive integer $k$ with $g^{k}=e$. If $g^{i}=g^{j}$ where $0\leq i<j<k$ then $g^{j-i}=e$.
But this cannot be true because $j-i$ is nonnegative and smaller than $k$. It contradicts the minimality of $k$.

Comment: @drhab, I have one silly doubt about order of generators. If I have a group with operation modulo 2 with an element 3. Then what would be $3^1$ ? Will it be 1 or 3? Is $3^1$ equivalent to $3*e$ where $e$ is an identity element of the group?

Comment: @RajeshR In every group $G$ with $a\in G$ it is true that $a^1=a$, so also $3^1=3$. If $3$ is actually not the integer $3$ but is an abbreviation of $3+2\mathbb Z$ and is an element of group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ then we have $3+2\mathbb Z=1+2\mathbb Z$ and this expression can be abbreviated by $3=1$. Also note that the identity of this group is not $1+2\mathbb Z$ (or abbreviated $1$) but is $2\mathbb Z$ (or abbreviated $0$).

Comment: @RajeshR My former comment might be a bit confusing. If we work in an abelian group (like $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$) then the notation $a^1$ is often not practicized, but is replaced by $a\cdot 1$. Here $1$ is an integer. Consistent with that notation - if $e$ denotes the identity - we do not have $3e=3$ but $3+e=3$. I said in my former comment that $3^1=3$ is also in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ but doing so I did not use that abelian notation. In the rest of the comment I did use it.

Comment: @drhab, thanks for replying. Actually I thought that it would be 1 because $3^1$ would be 3mod2 = 1 because for other orders like $3^2$ , it would be (3*3)mod2 = 1

Comment: @drhab, if possible can you please give me any reference where it's written that $a^1 = a$ and we need not apply any operator.

Comment: @drhab, I searched hard but couldn't find the statement that $a^1$ anywhere.

Comment: Wait! This shows that if $\lvert g\rvert=k$, then $\lvert G\rvert=k\,$ *but not vice versa*.

Comment: @Shaun If $|g|=k\implies|G|=k$ for every $k$ then it cannot happen that $|G|=k$ and $|g|\neq k$.

Comment: Ah, of course! I'm sorry! :)